# For a flow network, is it possible to show that there always exists a maximum flow which would assign integer values to all the edges?

Tags: graphs, network-flow

Is it possible to prove that for a flow network, there always exists a maximum flow which assigns an integer value to every edge?

Comment: Assuming you have integer capacities, yes. Yes or no questions are not particularly useful or suited to this site. Do you have a more involved question? (Also, just [searching](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~billups/courses/ma5490/lectures/lec12.pdf) will turn up a number of proofs in lots of lecture slides. Try to understand the proof - a request for the proof without demonstrating some attempt at understanding it will not be viewed particularly favourably.)

Answer (score 3):

If edges have real valued capacities, there may not exist a maximum flow which assigns an integer value to every edge. For example consider a single edged $s-t$ network with $c(s,t)=0.1$ where $c$ is capacity function. However if edges have integer valued capacity, there exists a maximum flow which assigns integer value to every edge because in each iteration of ford-fulkerson algorithm, each edge in residual graph is assigned an integer value. So the result is an integer.